# Second city won't load in single player mode

Tags: simcity-2013

When I try to start a 2nd city the load screen gets hung up. It keeps giving me different tips, but the city never loads. It says that I have claimed the city. Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

You have to start by playing your previous city, with the region tool, then  begin a new city.